# Why do the facets display the wrong amount of results ?

Tags: search

I have two facets that are bound to the **Content Type** and the **Publish Status** of my content.

[image]

When I do simple keywords search, it works properly, the amount of result corresponds to the real results displayed.

However, when I use double quotes to narrow down the search, the search works as expected, but the amount of result is completely messed up.

[image]

The search yielded only one result, but the amount of result is not correct.

All the indexes were rebuilt, the caches were cleared, but the issue remains. 
Where could this issue come from ?

I'm using Solr Version: 8.x-2.2 and Facets Version: 8.x-1.1

Comment: It must be related to your Search and Facets configuration, can you update your question with all the relevant information?

Comment: **Update** : the problem was kind of mixed. All this time, I was using the search box from the **Search** default module from Drupal, but the facets were bound to an index that was handled by **Solr**. After switching to Solr and using only Solr for every search, the numbers displayed are 100% correct. The issue I have now, is that my configuration of Solr doesn't handle double quotes ... I will formulate this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that time, I was using the default Search bar from Drupal 8 (which comes with the Search API module).

The thing is, the results in the facets were the ones that were given after **Solr** handled the search, and not the **Search** module from Search API.

For basic requests like a few keywords, both search engines yielded the same results, so the facets corresponded to the result, but my configuration of Solr didn't seem to handle double quotes.

In short : Search API handles the double quotes and displays the good results, but Solr didn't handle the double quotes so the facets results were wrong.